# Nucleo F303RE STLink connection problems in STM32CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, st-link, nucleo, stm32cubeide

I have tried to flash/debug Nucleo F303RE using STMCubeIDE and I have encountered several problems.

First when trying to start debugging I receive following message:

"Starting server with the following options:
[..]
SWD Debug                  : Enabled
InitWhile                  : Enabled
Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: ST-LINK firmware upgrade required. Please upgrade the ST-LINK firmware using the upgrade tool."

Then when I select "Open in update mode" in "STLinkUpgrade 3.4.0" tool I receive following message:
"Unexpected error during opening (1)"

Additionally STLinkUpgrade shows:
Current Firmware:
Type:
Version:   Unknown
Update to Firmware: Unknown

It looks strange.
It is not driver issues mentioned in STM documentation (Before connecting the Nucleo-64 board to a Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 10 PC via USB, a driver for ST-LINK/V2-1 must be installed. It can be downloaded from the [www.st.com](http://www.st.com) website. In case the STM32 Nucleo-64 board is connected to the PC before installing the driver, the PC device manager may report some Nucleo interfaces as “Unknown”.) because:

- I have downloaded and installed en.stsw-link009
- I am using Nucleo G491RE board and this board is working fine (no ST-Link issues)

I have also tried to connect using STM32CubeProgrammer and I was able to do it after unplugging and plugging again the board. It looks like this tool does not have problems with connection:

15:15:21 : UR connection mode is defined with the HWrst reset mode
15:15:21 : ST-LINK SN  : 066DFF343056363043032707
15:15:21 : ST-LINK FW  : V2J33M25
15:15:21 : Board       : NUCLEO-F303RE 
15:15:21 : Voltage     : 3.25V
15:15:21 : SWD freq    : 4000 KHz
15:15:21 : Connect mode: Normal
15:15:21 : Reset mode  : Software reset
15:15:21 : Device ID   : 0x446
15:15:21 : Revision ID : Rev Y
15:15:21 : Debug in Low Power mode is not supported for this device.
15:15:21 : UPLOADING OPTION BYTES DATA ...
15:15:21 :   Bank          : 0x00
15:15:21 :   Address       : 0x1ffff800
15:15:21 :   Size          : 16 Bytes
15:15:21 : UPLOADING ...
15:15:21 :   Size          : 1024 Bytes
15:15:21 :   Address       : 0x8000000
15:15:21 : Read progress:
15:15:21 : Data read successfully

Interestingly STM32CubeProgrammer Updater shows:
"No Updates available"
"Current version: v2.13.00"

How can I make it working under STMCubeIDE?

Comment: I managed to do a workaround and use OpenOCD for flashing and debugging inside STMCubeIDE.